# I don't understand a thing about strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, slice

I don't understand how this slicing thing works.

I have a variable that contains a string, variable = "String of the variable" and I need to flip it

I solved it using variable_name[ : : -1] But I still don't understand why this works, it is supposed that the first : are to put from where to where it goes and the last : to put every how many characters to take.

can someone explain to me?